# What does it mean to subtract from a type?

Tags: c++, types, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make sense of some ancient code, and I ran across what appears to be subtraction from a type. Is this an old C++ idiom? I've been trying to speculate, but if C++ has a 'type' type with an overloaded `operator-()`, I can't even guess what it would do.

```
int* array;
if(array[index] != (int)-1)
{
    //do things
}
```

(I've obviously refactored/removed things to boil this down; this code does compile and work, but even when I step through, I can't figure what this line is doing)
The parentheses around `int` might be a clue; I'm not sure what they could be doing.

Comment: This is -1 cast as an int.

Comment: It's a negation and you have UB.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm an idiot. Wow, wow, wow, long day. Thanks so much! Post as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: In the given code example, the cast is pointless anyway since `-1` is already of type `int`...

Comment: Conceivably this gives portability depending on how variations in compilers interpret literals.

Comment: @Akroy: if in the code it's always `-1`, there's no ambiguity - on any compiler it will be of type `int`. On the other way, if it's in a macro or whatever it may be needed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - `-1` is an `int`. Period. Using it in a macro doesn't change that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: my point is if that `-1` is actually a parameter to a macro, that he reported here expanded with its parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is `-1` cast as an `int`, not a subtraction.

As Jerry Coffin nicely pointed out, the cast is pointless (no pun intended) because that literal is of type `int` anyway.